# SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704 only on local development server

Tags: sql, db2

since today I am getting this weird SQL error on my local development Server. The Integration Test machine is fine even if I deploy the same artifacts on both.

I know this question has been asked before, but none of the answers seemed to solve my problem so far. I already tried to switch from the myBatis ${variable} to #{variable} and back. And I also tried putting all the table names in doublequotes.

Here is the error I get for every query I send to my local applicationserver (JBoss 6.1):

```
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SCHEME.TABLENAME DRIVER=3.63.75
### The error may exist in path/to/dao/mapper/DAOMapper.xml
### The error may involve path.to.dao.mapper.DAOMapper.daoMethod - inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT     VAL1 as VAL1,    VAL2 as VAL2, FROM SCHEME.TABLENAME  WHERE    VAR1=     (     select       MAX (VAR1)     FROM   SCHEME.TABLENAME    WHERE      VAR2 <= VAR2 )    WITH UR;
### Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SCHEME.TABLENAME, DRIVER=3.63.75; bad SQL grammar []; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SCHEME.TABLENAME, DRIVER=3.63.75: org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=SCHEME.TABLENAME, DRIVER=3.63.75
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `SQLCODE=-204` simply means that `SCHEME.TABLENAME` does not exist. Since this is obviously not the real error message, and the SQL is not the actual query, there isn't much beyond that I could tell you.

Comment: If the query is working in one database but not another, it could be caused by the tables being created in the wrong schema. If you examine the contents of the `TABSCHEMA` and `TABNAME` columns in the `SYSCAT.TABLES` catalog view for both databases (development and integration test), you may find a discrepancy between them that explains why the myBatis query is failing.

Comment: This is the actual Error Message and the real query. I just changed the field names and project-path. The "fun" thing is, that both Itest and dev use the same database. I can execute the query from Squirrel without a problem. And this issue showed up with no obvious reason to me, after changing some services logic.

Answer (score 0):

Case closed! As I was writing my comment, saying the two environements use the same database, I thought "Maybe not".

Turns out the datasource was configured wrong in the standalone.xml

I still have no idea how that happened though.